# Is there an efficient way of calculating the mean of multiple lists without doing it one by one (python)?

Tags: python

so basically i have 20 lists and i want to find the mean of those lists. however, i don't know how to manipulate the code in order to do it efficiently. currently i am plugging each list into the mean function one by one and it is very time consuming. is there any way that i can do this quickly?

each individual list of numbers is down below. help would be very much appreciated!

````
`import statistics
import math

def mean(data):
  answer = sum(data)/len(data)
  return answer

samples = [153.43, 161.45, 166.74, 167.28, 185.09]
[161.44, 175.4, 166.38, 174.19, 167.24]
[177.46, 176.65, 165.96, 171.52, 153.38]
[183.94, 189.5, 174.21, 176.17, 187.07]
[183.34, 165.49, 172.63, 158.5, 164.52]
[179.93, 172.61, 156.15, 165.89, 158.5]
[164.91, 174.71, 178.26, 176.74, 188.23]
[188.7, 181.8, 174.1, 167.18, 166.6]
[168.44, 162.14, 174.66, 173.89, 177.69]
[183.84, 161.34, 165.76, 173.74, 173.39]
[156.99, 173.59, 174.17, 177.2, 164.2]
[166.34, 179.78, 160.13, 166.54, 169.55]
[164.3, 172.07, 167.35, 184.02, 174.3]
[161.53, 161.77, 171.62, 165.17, 190.27]
[173.94, 170.21, 173.68, 172.77, 166.62]
[165.76, 156.93, 160.18, 166.27, 169.14]
[183.99, 174.7, 159.05, 161.27, 164.46]
[155.29, 161.3, 164.67, 174.18, 171.12]
[180.6, 177.58, 168.16, 173.81, 161.27]
[191.13, 170.21, 166.62, 173.56, 171.56]
```
``
````

Comment: Since your code is actually working and you're looking for performances, this question would be better fitted for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: After turning samples in to a list of lists, running `print(*(mean(s) for s in samples))` took 0.1sec on my ancient laptop.

Answer (score 0):

That code isn't valid.

If we make `samples` a list of lists:

```py
import statistics
import math

def mean(data):
  answer = sum(data)/len(data)
  return answer

samples = [
    [153.43, 161.45, 166.74, 167.28, 185.09],
    [161.44, 175.4, 166.38, 174.19, 167.24],
    [177.46, 176.65, 165.96, 171.52, 153.38],
    [183.94, 189.5, 174.21, 176.17, 187.07],
    [183.34, 165.49, 172.63, 158.5, 164.52],
    [179.93, 172.61, 156.15, 165.89, 158.5],
    [164.91, 174.71, 178.26, 176.74, 188.23],
    [188.7, 181.8, 174.1, 167.18, 166.6],
    ...
]

for i in samples:
    print(mean(i))
```

If you want the mean of *all* the list values you can edit the for loop at the bottom:

```py
count = 0
for i in samples:
    count += mean(i)

print(count/len(samples))
```

Comment: @Cid I corrected the error and provided a solution (the for loop at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

I think I do not understand you all, but you mean like following code?

```
import math

def mean(data):
  answer = sum(data)/len(data)
  return answer

samples = [[153.43, 161.45, 166.74, 167.28, 185.09],[153.43, 161.45, 166.74, 167.28, 185.09]
]
total = []
for sample_list in samples:
    for one_data in sample_list:
        total.append(one_data)
print(mean(total))
```